# OMNeT++ : how to display only specific logs during simulation?

Tags: omnet++, inet

To learn how to use the OMNeT++ simulator, I made a wireless network like this :

```
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.physicallayer.wireless.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
import inet.node.inet.WirelessHost;


network WirelessNetwork
{
    parameters:
        @display("bgb=600,600");
        
    submodules:
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {@display("p=550,475");}
        radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {@display("p=550,550");}
        HostA: WirelessHost {@display("p=140,200");}
        HostB: WirelessHost {@display("p=450,200");}
}
```

Now, when I run the simulation, a lot of logs are displayed, like this :

```
INFO: Transmission ended: (inet::physicallayer::WirelessSignal)ProbeReq (38 us 39 B) (inet::Packet)ProbeReq (39 B) (inet::SequenceChunk) length = 39 B WHOLE as Ieee80211ScalarTransmission
INFO: Changing radio transmission state from TRANSMITTING to IDLE.
INFO (Dcf)WirelessNetwork.HostA.wlan[0].mac.dcf: Finishing last frame sequence step: history = (MANAGEMENT)
INFO (Dcf)WirelessNetwork.HostA.wlan[0].mac.dcf: Processing transmitted frame ProbeReq as originator in frame sequence.
INFO (Dcf)WirelessNetwork.HostA.wlan[0].mac.dcf: For the current frame exchange, we have CW = 31 SRC = 0 LRC = 0 SSRC = 0 and SLRC = 0
INFO (Dcf)WirelessNetwork.HostA.wlan[0].mac.dcf: Starting next frame sequence step: history = (MANAGEMENT)
INFO (Dcf)WirelessNetwork.HostA.wlan[0].mac.dcf: Frame sequence finished.
INFO (Dcaf)WirelessNetwork.HostA.wlan[0].mac.dcf.channelAccess: Channel released.
INFO: Changing radio transmitted signal part from WHOLE to NONE.
```

I want to display some specific logs, and disable others that I don't need.

I searched how to do this, and the only way I found is to edit the `.cc` files, but I can't because I import these files. Is there another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some options to control presenting of messages after starting a simulation in Qtenv mode. They are described in the following sections of [User Guide](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/UserGuide.pdf):

- 7.7.2 "Logs", where settings of log level are described
- 7.7.5 "Timeline and Animation Filtering", when one can add a filter to exclude messages